# R is commutative ring with identity & define $\circ$ on $R$ by for any $a,b \in R$ $a \circ b=a+b-ab$ Prove the following

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, ring-theory

Let R be a commutative ring with identity. Define a new operation $\circ$ on $R$ by for any $a,b \in R$

$$a \circ b=a+b-ab$$

a) Prove that $\circ$ is associative

b) Prove that R is a field iff the set $\{r \in R: r \ne 1\}$ is an abelian group with respect to the operation $\circ$

Starting with a) we must prove

$a \circ ( b \circ c)= (a \circ b) \circ c$

Left side: $a \circ ( b \circ c)=a \circ (b+c-bc)=a+b+c-bc-a(b+c-bc)=a+b+c-bc-ab-ac+abc$

Right side: $(a \circ b) \circ c =(a+b-ab) a \circ c=a+b-ab+c-(a+b-ab)c=a+b-ab+c-ac-bc+abc$ and we have thus proved that $\circ$ is associative

As for part b), I am a little confused on what is being asked exactly. Is it asking to go through ALL the properties of a field, closure, associativity, commutativity, identity, inverse, distributive, showing that all hold except for when $r \ne 1$?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The proof for part (a) is good.

For part (b) you just have to show that any nonzero element in $R$ has a multiplicative inverse and $0\ne1$ if and only if $(R\setminus\{1\},\circ)$ is an abelian group.

The other field properties are already guaranteed by the fact that $R$ is a commutative ring.

If $(R\setminus\{1\},\circ)$ is a group, then it is nonempty, so $0\ne1$ (note that $0$ is the neutral element for the circle operation). Let $a\in R$, $a\ne0$. Then $1-a\ne1$, so $1-a$ has an inverse with respect to the circle operation: $(1-a)\circ b=0$, that is
$$
(1-a)+b-(1-a)b=0
$$
or
$$
1-a+ab=0
$$
and so $a(1-b)=1$. Thus $a^{-1}=1-b$.

Suppose $R$ is a field and consider $a\in R\setminus\{1\}$. You want to find an inverse of $a$ with respect to the circle operation, that is $b$ such that $a+b-ab=0$. This becomes $b(a-1)=a$ or $b=a(a-1)^{-1}$ (note that $a-1\ne0$, so $(a-1)^{-1}$ exists). Also $a(a-1)^{-1}\ne1$ because otherwise $a=a-1$ or $1=0$ which is false in a field.

Comment: I think in the last sentence you mean $1=0$ ($1\ne 0$ doesn't follow from $a=a-1$ and is certainly not false in a field).

Comment: @celtschk Yes, you're right.

Answer (score 2):

**Hint** $ $ Any set bijection $\,h\,:\,R'\to R\,$ serves to [transport the multiplicative structure](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/4351523/242) of $\,(R,*,1),$ to $\,(R',\circ,1') \,$ by defining the operations in $\,R'\,$ to make $\,h\,$ be an isomorphism

$$\begin{align}  &a \circ b\, =\, h^{-1}(h(a)\, * h(b)),\quad\, 1' = h^{-1}(1)\end{align}\qquad \qquad$$

Yours is the special case $\ h(x) = 1-x$